# Второй и последующие запросы из Android-приложения на сервер возвращают ошибку 400 (Bad request)

Tags: java, android, spring, rest

Первый запрос выполняется, а второй выдает ошибку 400 и приложение закрывается.
Этот класс используется для выполнения запросов из приложения на сервер:

```
private  class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        template.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        lgn = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.login) ;
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password) ;

        return template.getForObject(Constants.URL.HOST+"login/login="+lgn.getText()+"&password="+pass.getText(), String.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String str) {
       //какие-то действия

    }
}
```

логи ошибки

```
 01-10 09:54:19.052 8119-8140/com.team.sarafanka.sarafanka W/RestTemplate: GET request for "http://192.168.1.47:8080/login/login=lox&password=1234" resulted in 400 (); invoking error handler
01-10 09:54:19.062 8119-8140/com.team.sarafanka.sarafanka E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                            Process: com.team.sarafanka.sarafanka, PID: 8119
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                                                                         Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 
                                                                            at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:88)
                                                                            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:585)
                                                                            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:541)
                                                                            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:499)
                                                                            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:264)
                                                                            at com.team.sarafanka.sarafanka.activities.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:45)
                                                                            at com.team.sarafanka.sarafanka.activities.LoginActivity$LoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:36)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                                                                            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: Кстати, в браузере запрос выполняется полностью и сколько угодно раз

Comment: Новое наблюдение. Если после первого запроса подождать минутку другую, то следующий запрос так же выполняется нормально.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить заголовки. Быть может тип и keep-alive Вам поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что вы пропустили `?` в параметрах HTTP запроса

Т.е. валидные параметры передаются примерно так:

```
http://192.168.1.47:8080/login?login=lox&password=1234
```

Comment: Первый запрос обрабатывается корректно и выполняется. Изменил текст запроса на сервера, что бы он был таким, как вы сказали - не помогло. Все также - первый запрос выполняется, а второй уже с ошибкой